# How to subtract lines of A that happens in B?

Tags: bash, sh

I want to filter the output of `pacman` command using the output of a previous `pacman` command and send the result into a file, the idea is the get rid of repetitions in the first output that exists too in the second.

Let's say:

```
a=`pacman -Qm`
# This produces the output
# package1 v0.0
# package2 v0.0
# packageN v0.0
b=`pacman -Qet`
# This produces the output
# package9 v0.0
# package2 v0.0
# packageN v0.0
```

What I want is to produce this output:

```
package1 v0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if commands output can be taken in files then required can be achieved using **comm** command

comm - compare two sorted files line by line

eg. below

```
$pacman -Qm | sort > file1.txt
$pacman -Qet | sort > file2.txt

# in below command
# -2 suppress lines unique to file2.txt, 
# -3 supresses lines which appear in both files
# output will have only lines which are unique to file1.txt
$ comm -2 -3 file1.txt file2.txt > file3.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

use **diff**: http://linux.die.net/man/1/diff 
pipe the outputs to 2 files. diff the files.